# How can I resize text to fit on a fixed UILabel and/or UITextView

Tags: ios, resize, uitextview, uilabel, uifont

I have a fixed-size UILabel and/or UITextView and I need to fit variable, multiline text in these views.

I don't want to resize the views, but rather the text. So that, regardless of my text being 1 line or 12 lines, it still always fits in the fixed-size view.

How would I go about this?

I'd think there would be an answer to this somewhere, but so far I always run into the opposite of my question, or I run into replies suggesting autoresize, sizeToFit or sizeWithFont: and neither seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

check out [UIKit's NSString additions](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html), in particular sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:

You could use a "for" loop that increases the size of the UIFont until the size exceeds the UILabel or UITextView.